# How to create a request-scoped bean manually?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a request-scoped bean which are used in app. Now I need to implement some predefined configuration beans. I tried both ways:

1. as a `InitializingBean` implementation
2. as a spring's `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` listener

but the problem is that code within this config beans uses erquest-scoped bean and everytime I get a:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread`?

is there any way of simulating request?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Stefan as I said I need to do something on startup (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle) and the code uses request-scoped bean.

Comment: "as I said I need to do something on startup" - yes, but the question is what? The request object represents a request to your application by a client, usually http. You dont have that at startup, so that code cannot use the bean. But the bean can use the code, if its was stored in the ServletContext or in a Service, at startup.

Comment: @Stefan "But the bean can use the code, if its was stored in the ServletContext or in a Service, at startup" - could you please specify what exactly did you mean?